# LandScape Orientation Issue while presenting UIImagePickerController in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

While presenting UIImagePickerController in Landscape Mode,it rotates to portrait mode instead of Landscape.I have this issue in my iPad but in Simulator its working fine.Can any one please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Like this :

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: getting conflicting return type as a warning

Comment: Then simply use - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations